# Why can't NAD+ undergo single-electron reduction?

Tags: biochemistry, resonance, organic-reduction

$\ce{FAD}$ can undergo single-electron reduction to form a stable radical, which can then be reduced again to $\ce{FADH2}$. This is supposedly possible due to resonance stability, where the unpaired electron is delocalised amongst the molecule. In $\ce{NAD+}$ however, the free radical formed is very unstable, so it can only undergo hydride-mediated (or two-electron) reduction.

This sounds simple by itself, but the diagram I found (shown below), in my opinion, contradicts this claim.

[image: fad nad]

It seems to me that $\ce{NAD+}$ is just as capable in forming resonance structures as $\ce{FAD}$; the double bonds are adjacent to the unpaired electron and the lone pair on the carbon (in $\ce{NAD+}$) should be in a p-orbital, which also allows it to be delocalised. It is true that $\ce{FAD}$ is larger and has more aromatic rings, which makes it a better candidate to undergo single-electron reduction; however, $\ce{NAD+}$ should **ALSO** be able to form radicals, albeit not as often. Contrary to that, it is said that the $\ce{NAD}$ radical is very rare or even non-existent.

The source I mainly used (due to lack of others) is this [Chemistry LibreTexts site](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Wade)/09%3A_Reactions_of_Alkenes/9.18_Biological_Additions_of_Radicals_to__Alkenes). If anyone can point out the reasoning behind this oddity, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: The difference between “not as often” and “very rare” is semantic. There is also the issue of evolved function. NAD is not utilized by enzymes that catalyze one electron transfers